# Testing asynchronous $rootScope broadcasts with controller using $on

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have code similar to this...

```
//controller
function getPromise = function(){
   return service.getPromise();
}
$rootScope.$on('event', function(){
   return getPromise();
});
```

I am trying to create a jasmine test for the rootScope event. I can test the function itself (if I expose it) by using a .then and checking for the result, but I can't figure out how to do it through the on call.

Comment: Thats a unit test? if so you do not need to test if the rootscope.$on('event') gets called on broadcast, you only need to test the underlying method (which you said you are already doing it.).

Comment: Agreeing with @PSL. What you should test is: When `event` is fired -> Assert `service.getPromise` is called. Testing the actual `$on` method is the Angular team´s job.

Comment: Good points the problem I have is when there is more complex logic in the event handler, but maybe that can just be abstracted.